# Editing a cell after cloning a row seems to update cells for both rows instead of the one that's changed

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am using `ag-grid` for Angular. I have 3 buttons (Add, Clone and Delete).

1. Click Add button once. It adds one row.
2. Select 1st row and click "Clone" button. It clones the row.
3. In the new row, double click and change value in any cell. It over-writes the first row with the second row values after cell editing is complete.

How do I prevent that from happening?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sgqsab?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Here's the component code:

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {
  
  gridApi;
  gridColumnApi;
  rowSelection;

  
  defaultColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 100,
    resizable: true,
    editable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filter: false
  };

  columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'Make', field: 'make' },
    { headerName: 'Model', field: 'model' },
    { headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'},
    { headerName: 'Miles', field: 'miles' },
    { headerName: 'Age', field: 'age'}
  ];
  
  rowData = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.rowSelection = 'multiple';
  }

  onGridReady = (params) => {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
  }

  addRow() {
    this.gridApi.applyTransaction({
      add: [{ "make": 'Toyota', "model": 'Corolla', "price": '$10,000', "miles": '100', "age": '1997' }],
      addIndex:0 
    });
  }

  deleteRow() {
    var selectedData = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
    this.gridApi.applyTransaction({remove: selectedData});
  }

  cloneRow() {
    var selectedData = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
    this.gridApi.applyTransaction({add: selectedData});
  }

  onCellEditingStopped(event) {
    console.log(this.getAllRows())
  }

  getAllRows() {
    let myData = [];
    for(let i=0;i<this.gridApi.getModel().rowsToDisplay.length;i++) {
      myData.push(this.gridApi.getModel().rowsToDisplay[i].data);
    }
    return myData;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried constructing a new instance and assigning the properties from the selected row instead of just inserting the selected row back into the add? It could be possible they reference the same record even though it takes up two rows.

Comment: I have not tried that and not sure how to do so. You are probably right about the references though. Must be something internal.

Comment: @Jake for now the easiest thing you can just do something like var toAdd = { make: selectedData["make"], model: selectedData["model"], etc... }; and then pass that into the applyTransaction function. If that doesn't work then I guess my hunch was wrong

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. Had to use the zero index for `selectedData` to make it work. `var toAdd = { make: selectedData[0]["make"], model: selectedData[0]["model"], etc... };`